# Delete Queues and Exchanges on RabbitMQ with HTTP API

Tags: api, http, curl, rabbitmq

I'have a question, I want to delete Queues and Exchanges on RabbitMQ with Curl and HTTP API.

I wanna use 2 options `--if-empty=true` and `--if-unused=true`.

but when I use it with curl, I have a error.

```
kalenas@localhost:~$ curl -XDELETE ${RABBIT_URL}/api/queues/<scope>/<queue> --if-empty=true --if-unused=true;
curl: option --if-empty=true: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Have you a idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`curl -XDELETE $RABBIT_URL/api/queues/$VHOST/<queue> -G -d 'if-empty=true' -d 'if-empty=true'`